# OAuth with Azure AD v2.0: What is the ext_expires_in parameter returned by Azure AD v2.0 in response to access token requests?

Tags: azure-active-directory

According to the [Azure AD documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code), the Section “Request an access token” describes all the parameter keys that should be returned by Azure AD in response to access token requests via Azure v2.0 endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my_tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`.  Example of response body returned by Azure AD v2.0:

```
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "scope": "User.Read",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "ext_expires_in": 0,
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiO ...",
  "refresh_token": "OAQABAAAAAAA9kTklh ..."
  "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC ..."
```

The documentation does NOT mention `ext_expires_in` as one of the returned parameters.  My questions are:

- What is the definition of this key?
- What kind of other expiration does `ext_expires_in` describe in addition to the current `expires_in` key currently does?

Answer (score 7):

This claim is used to support resiliency. It is used to achieve uninterrupted services access even during an STS outage. The server may return the ext_expires_in value to indicate the extended lifetime of an access token.
For more details you can see how ADAL uses this information:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/issues/675

Comment: Jean-Marc, can you confirm - if we don't opt into the outage behavior, expires_in is the value to go with for when the access_token will expire?  And ext_expires_in will only come into play if/when there's an outage and we opt into the outage behavior?  I'm looking to use this as a better alternative to decoding the access_token to then check the exp in the payload (as I've been advised this is bad practice and soon access_token's will be encrypted).